# Increase a counter in the first interface controller by pressing a button in the second interface controller

Tags: swift, watchkit

I would like to increase the value of the property in the first interface controller in the IBAction (Add1) method of the second interface controller

and then use the value of this property to update the label when the first view controller is activated

- I was able to increase the value , but the value increases even if I press the back button.
- I need to find a solution so that when I press the IBAction in the second interface controller , I can get that result and use it in the first interface controller and update the label.

here is the code:

First interface controller:

> Blockquote

```
@IBOutlet weak var resultButtonLabel: WKInterfaceButton!

@IBAction func resultButton() {
  pushControllerWithName("secondInterfaceController", context: self)

}

override func willActivate() {
    super.willActivate()
    resultButtonLabel.setTitle("\(counter++)")
}
```

> Blockquote

Second interface controller:

> Blockquote

```
  var counter = 1

@IBAction func weScored() {
    counter++
    popController()

}
```

> Blockquote

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way to implement this idea is use of `NSUserDefaults`

In your firstViewController you can read values form `NSUserDefaults` this way:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let score = NSUserDefaults().integerForKey("Score")
    resultButtonLabel.text = "\(score)"
}
```

and into your SecondViewController you can increase this counter with `NSUserDefaults` this way:

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

var counter = Int()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    counter = NSUserDefaults().integerForKey("Score")
}
@IBAction func weScored(sender: AnyObject) {

    counter++
    NSUserDefaults().setInteger(counter, forKey: "Score")
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! UIViewController
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Do you think I could do the same steps using Watchkit, because my App is on the Apple Watch so i won't be able to use (UIStoryboard, and presentViewController and UIKit in general )

Comment: You can modify code as pr ur need.but logic will be same i think.

Comment: For example I didn't find the equivalent of UIStoryboard in Watchkit.

Comment: Did you try pushControllerWithName?

Comment: I'm using 
pushControllerWithName("SecondInterfaceController", context : self)
in the first InterfaceController.
and then I'm increasing the counter in the 2nd IC in The IBAction.
Now I want to send back the result of the counter++ and use it in the first Interface Controller

Comment: Read Docs about NSUserDefaults and you will find solution..:)

Comment: Thank you , I have figured out  a solution using NSUserDefaults, Is there a way to refresh and set the counter to zero ?

Comment: Yes you can set it to 0 when view load first time.

Comment: I have a button that starts the game, can I set the NSUserDefaults property to O everytime the user presses that button ?